# How to show the image from the local file path example from c:/foldername/x.png

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-windows

I would like to show the image from the File path example from c:/foldername/x.png. When I have given file path, we are getting cross mark but it is not loading the image, anyone has any idea?
Code which I was working

```
<Image source={require('C:/Users/username/Pictures/66.png')}
      style={{
        width:220,
        height:220,
        borderWidth:2,
        borderColor:'#d35647',
        resizeMode:'stretch',
        margin:8
      }}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have for example, the follow scafolding

```
src
|____/assets
|_________imgs
|_____________mi-img.png
|____/components
|_________/MyImage
|_____________MyComponent.js
```

in `MyComponent.js` you must access to your image in the follow way:

```
<Image source={require('../../assets/imgs/mi-img.png')}
      style={{
        width:220,
        height:220,
        borderWidth:2,
        borderColor:'#d35647',
        resizeMode:'stretch',
        margin:8
      }}
    />
```

Comment: I can able to load with this relative path with respect to the project. However, the requirement is to load from a fixed path as mentioned in the above question.

Comment: Hmm in that case IMHO is convenience upload the img to some server, because when you compile the app the bundle doesn't has a C disk for example, the device doesn't has the folder structure that you're passing as argument, that folder path is valid in your computer

Comment: I mean, upload to some server or put the image in the project folder